# Manipulate VTK vertex fields

Tags: graphics3d, manipulate, import, finite-element-method

I have a VTK file that contains several **vertex fields**, and I'd like to manipulate the view.

The objective is to **show/hide all vertices whose field match a certain function**.

For instance, if I have a temperature field, I'd like to show (all triangles) with `T > -20`, or even something useless like `Sin[T*Norm[NormalVector]] < 0.5`. However, I have no idea on how to achieve this, or how to even access one particular field in the VTK file.

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The current version of the [VTK Import](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/VTK.html), I think, only reads legacy format and ignores vertex fields.

Comment: @TimLaska thanks for your comment. As far as I see, in "*Import Elements*" it is possible to use the `PointData` option, with (quoting) "*point data in indexed form*". Maybe there is a possibility there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the current version of *Mathematica* (12.1.1) import functionality of VTK files seems restricted to legacy format files, and it appears to ignore field data.

## Sample VTK file

Here's a simple example of a cube with scaler nodal data taken from [here](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/VTKFileFormats/).

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
writeScript[filename_, txt_] := Module[{file},
  file = OpenWrite[filename];
  WriteString[file, txt];
  Close[file]]
runScript[] := RunProcess["run_script.bat"]
(*Legacy VTK format cube example*)
cubevtk = "# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
  Cube example
  ASCII
  DATASET POLYDATA
  POINTS 8 float
  0.0 0.0 0.0
  1.0 0.0 0.0
  1.0 1.0 0.0
  0.0 1.0 0.0
  0.0 0.0 1.0
  1.0 0.0 1.0
  1.0 1.0 1.0
  0.0 1.0 1.0
  POLYGONS 6 30
  4 0 1 2 3
  4 4 5 6 7
  4 0 1 5 4
  4 2 3 7 6
  4 0 4 7 3
  4 1 2 6 5
  CELL_DATA 6
  SCALARS cell_scalars int 1
  LOOKUP_TABLE default
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  NORMALS cell_normals float
  0 0 -1
  0 0 1
  0 -1 0
  0 1 0
  -1 0 0
  1 0 0
  FIELD FieldData 2
  cellIds 1 6 int
  0 1 2 3 4 5
  faceAttributes 2 6 float
  0.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0
  POINT_DATA 8
  SCALARS sample_scalars float 1
  LOOKUP_TABLE my_table
  0.0
  1.0
  2.0
  3.0
  4.0
  5.0
  6.0
  7.0
  LOOKUP_TABLE my_table 8
  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
  1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
  0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
  1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
  0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
  1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
  0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0";
writeScript["cube.vtk", cubevtk]
SetEnvironment["TIMSVTK_FILE" -> "cube.vtk"]
```

We can use a post-processor (e.g., EnSight) to view the cube.VTK file and color it by the `samples_scalars` variable as shown in the following image.

[image: EnSight image]

## *Mathematica* VTK import

The following code shows which elements *Mathematica* imports.

```
elems = ImportString[cubevtk, "Elements"];
data = {Text[#], ImportString[cubevtk, #]} & /@ elems;
Text@Grid[Prepend[data, {"Element", "Returned"}], 
  Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White, 
      Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}}, 
  Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]}, 
     Darker[Gray, .6]}, {Darker[Gray, .6], Darker[Gray, .6], {False}, 
     Darker[Gray, .6]}}, Alignment -> {{Left, Right, {Left}}}, 
  Frame -> Darker[Gray, .6], ItemStyle -> 14, 
  Spacings -> {Automatic, .8}]
```

[image: Import elements]

Under `PointData`, where `sample_scalars` should exist, returns an empty brace. There may be a way to get *Mathematica* to import the scalar field, but I have not found it. Alternatively, one could use *Mathematica* interoperability capability and tap into one of the freely available Python libraries to extract the field data. I will show one such approach.

## Approach using external Python libraries

It is fairly straightforward to install [VTK](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/vtk) and [PyVista](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyvista) under the Anaconda Python distribution. PyVista provides a "pythonic" interface to several types of mesh formats.

Here's an approach that I threw together that works under Windows 10. It uses a Windows batch file, `run_script.bat` to activate the appropriate Anaconda environment and run a Python script. I chose to use environment variables to pass in the script name and arguments versus using command-line arguments in this example. The first Python script `get_arr_names.py` returns a list of the available arrays in the VTK file. The second Python script, `get_arr_values.py`, will write an output file of the scalar values based on the array name.

```
winbatch = 
  Uncompress[
   "1:eJx9jzEPAUEQhfkfilFoBeVVRBQKidgTzSSyZkdu4m5Hdhfn37s7RKd975s37w1P\
ujODfq83ZyoU9HzGyXSWZXAQ7/QR4WQTFRApyDUB2bIE0qqy3oFEKOXCYBsmNojeAvHX/\
aSYt5gKBsdRAjtYeEvqnQX2dwnqK/\
appbvsZYa4jxwiYi4V4heeIZquQmNYSnK3icdNtT8H7wKrmumWft+3z1So/+\
xpmWsnjLlmGOXrjTma5W69zUetx7V0zAvEmGVI"];
writeScript["run_script.bat", winbatch];

getarrnames = 
  Uncompress[
   "1:eJxTTMoPCp7FwMCQmVuQX1SiUFBZlllckqiQWKxQUBZjYGgEFc8vBnFAuKwkOy0z\
J1XBFiiml5pXllmUnxetFOLpGxwW4h3v5unjqhQLUpebWpwBVFRQpleUmpiiAdWmCZIqLk\
3KSk0uKQZKg1TpJRYVJVbG5yUCOSDpgqLMvBINmCJNAHwpN6w="];
writeScript["get_arr_names.py", getarrnames];

getarrvals = 
  Uncompress[
   "1:eJxtj8FOwzAMhsebmJ5agaLBncMOIE3ApZuQUKmqtKRaBk0iJ43oc/\
GCOJ077cAhku3/8/87160td79Xq5UenMUAZhzcBNKDcR/ru3ueWn/\
RuClqH2SCXLyYo0pNejF89fpbwQMtCmWiRmuqbL993b3tn5un7ctjVjMnEf/\
Bmk1Zbt5PkB0DmzF+\
A5mgYbakDcofSHVRoJKfOYcXSfJje1Rd8CQnStC6nBojqUkyKtseSUMlOjs42spPGcXiTX\
WiianYC3qLsNTawDlC9zD7Ca8kdoechaKu1jVbLWc4q01o5mN8xREz45CEnH88H2Gc8DKq\
8HMe38Jy4B+cC5g4"];
writeScript["get_arr_values.py", getarrvals];
```

First, we will get a list of the available array names. Of which, we see `sample_scalars` is available.

```
SetEnvironment["TIMS_SCRIPT" -> "get_arr_names.py"]; 
runScript[]["StandardOutput"]
(* "['sample_scalars', 'cell_scalars', 'cell_normals', \
'cellIds', 'faceAttributes']
" *)
```

Now, we can write `sample_scalars` to an output file and read into *Mathematica*.

```
(*Write sample_scalars to output file and read into MMA*)
SetEnvironment[{"TIMS_SCRIPT" -> "get_arr_values.py", 
  "TIMS_ARRAY" -> "sample_scalars"}]
scalarfile = StringTrim@runScript[]["StandardOutput"];
scalarvals = Flatten@Import[scalarfile];
(*Read in vertex data*)
vertices = ImportString[cubevtk, "VertexData"];
{min, max} = MinMax@vertices;
```

We can create an interpolation function based on the `VertexData` and the `sample_scalars`. The image matches closely to what we obtained with EnSight.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[vertices];
interp = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, scalarvals];
mr = MeshRegion@ToElementMesh[Cuboid[min {1, 1, 1}, max {1, 1, 1}]];
SliceContourPlot3D[
 interp[x, y, z], mr, {x, min, max}, {y, min, max}, {z, min, 
  max}, Contours -> 17, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"]
```

[image: Mathematica interpolation]